# Конфигурация Hibernate

Tags: intellij-idea, hibernate

Нужен ли в проекте, при использовании Hibernate, файл hibernate.cfg.xml для настроек конфигураций Hibernate? Или это старый подход?

Answer (score 1):

Сконфигурироватьнужно обязательно dataSource и sessionFactory, указать ему параметры для подключения к бд. Настройки hibernate можно произвести как через hibernate.cfg.xml, так и через аннотации. Мне больше по душе конфигурирование через аннотации, поэтому выкладываю свой стандартный конфиг, возможно пригодится:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfiguration
{
private final Environment _environment;

@Autowired
public HibernateConfiguration(Environment _environment) {this._environment = _environment;}

@Bean(name = "flyway", initMethod = "migrate")
public Flyway flyway() throws Exception
{
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setDataSource(restDataSource());
    flyway.setLocations("../migration");
    flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
    flyway.setBaselineVersionAsString("0.0.1");
    flyway.repair();
    return flyway;
}

@DependsOn({"flyway"})
@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws PropertyVetoException
{
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("....entity"); //Необходимо указать пакет, где находятся персистентные классы
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource restDataSource() throws PropertyVetoException
{
    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClass(_environment.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(_environment.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUser(_environment.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
    dataSource.setPassword(_environment.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));

    dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(1);
    dataSource.setMinPoolSize(1);
    dataSource.setAcquireIncrement(1);
    dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(60 * 10);
    dataSource.setMaxConnectionAge(60 * 60 * 24);
    dataSource.setAutomaticTestTable("system_connection_test_table");
    dataSource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(60 * 4);

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    return txManager;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties()
{
    return new Properties()
    {
        {
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", _environment.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", _environment.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
            setProperty("hibernate.connection.CharSet", "utf8");
            setProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "utf8");
            setProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", "true");
            setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", _environment.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        }
    };
}
```

}